# Update Core Data without having to change screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, core-data

After I update my Core Data store - by deleting then adding the data - in a different thread, I'm required to change the screen and then go back for the data to update it. Is there a way to do update Core Data without having to change the screen in the app?

code to reset database:

```
- (void) resetDatabase {
    count++;

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){
        ConDAO *con = [[ConDAO alloc] init];
        DatabaseManager *manager = [DatabaseManager sharedManager];
        NSError * error;
        NSURL * storeURL = [[[manager managedObjectContext] persistentStoreCoordinator] URLForPersistentStore:[[[[manager managedObjectContext] persistentStoreCoordinator] persistentStores] lastObject]];
        [[manager managedObjectContext] reset];//to drop pending changes
        if ([[[manager managedObjectContext] persistentStoreCoordinator] removePersistentStore:[[[[manager managedObjectContext] persistentStoreCoordinator] persistentStores] lastObject] error:&error])
        {
            // remove the file containing the data
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:storeURL error:&error];
            //recreate the store like in the  appDelegate method
            [[[manager managedObjectContext] persistentStoreCoordinator] addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error];//recreates the persistent store
        }
        NSLog(@"*****************************");
        NSLog(@"updating");
        NSLog(@"count: %d", count);
        NSLog(@"*****************************");

        [self populateDatabase:0 con:con];


        NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:60.0
                                                 target:self
                                               selector:@selector(resetDatabase)
                                               userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
        [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

                });
        });
}
```

Code that runs when ui is changed:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    // Setup KVO for verifyingcard
    [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"verifyingCard" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];

    if([BluetoothTech isEqualToString:@"BLE"]){
        self.centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil options:@{CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey: @YES}];
    }
    else if([BluetoothTech isEqualToString:@"HID"]){
        [self.bluetoothScanTextView becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    [self loadStudents];
}
```

I think it has to do with the loadStudents() function, but when I use NSNotificationCenter to run it from the other class, it still doesnt work.

LoadStudent code:

```
- (void)loadStudents{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Caf_student_cards"];
    NSArray *arr = [[self.manager managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    for(int i = 0; i < [arr count]; i++){
        if([[[arr objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"user_id"] isEqualToString:@"201509061"]){
            NSLog(@"%@",[arr objectAtIndex:i]);
        }
    }
    if(!error){
        self.caf_student_cards = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:arr];
        self.keys = [[[arr.firstObject entity] attributesByName] allKeys];
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"%s %s %s","\n\n\n",[[error localizedDescription] UTF8String],"\n\n\n");
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // Show alert to tell user to reload this page
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]] message:@"Check connection and relog back into cafeteria." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the connection between updating CoreData and changing UI ??

Comment: I'm not sure, but it only updates when I change the ui screen

Comment: How can that be possible dude ?? Core data update got nothing do with UI update. Please post some code to clarify ur case

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44546194/ios-error-when-calling-viewwillappear-manually-objective-c related to this - fixed the error but need to change ui for it to work

Comment: There is nothing about Core Data that requires UI updates to work. If you're finding some connection, you need to post information about what **exactly** you are doing, and about what happens when you update your UI.

Comment: added code and what I think might be causing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple problems with this code.

The one most directly relevant to your question is that you're updating your persistent store, **but not updating your UI**. It doesn't happen automatically. If you have new data, you need to tell your UI to update. How to do that depends on what kind of UI you have. If it's a table view, it might be as simple as telling the table view to reload its data. If you have an array that you use to hold the UI's data, you would need to update that too (it looks like this might be what `caf_student_cards` is in your code but it's impossible to be sure.

Other problems-- and these are **major** problems that you need to fix immediately:

1. You're doing Core Data multithreading wrong. Using `dispatch_async` is not effective here. You need to use `performBlock` or `performBlockAndWait` on your managed object context, or else `performBackgroundTask` on your persistent container.
2. You're removing the main persistent store file but not removing the journal files. This is pretty much guaranteed to either prevent old data from being deleted or else simply cause data corruption. What you're doing is not a useful technique. Removing the persistent store files is rarely a good idea. If you want to get rid of existing data, delete it from Core Data, maybe by telling your context to `delete` the objects or else by using `NSBatchDeleteRequest`.

There may be others. This code is a mess. You would be doing yourself a huge favor if you spent a little time looking over Apple's [Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html?utm_source=iosstash.io).

Also you [keep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44546194/ios-error-when-calling-viewwillappear-manually-objective-c) asking nearly the [same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44506977/error-when-updating-core-data-in-the-background) question [repeatedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44508600/how-to-reload-ui-on-ios-objective-c). You've had some good advice, but you don't seem to be taking any of it. If you want more information, go and read over other answers people have already given when you've posted this question before.

Comment: thanks, but in terms of reloading the array. I call the function that does this but it still doesnt work. When I input a certain key it says it doesnt exist unless I change the screen.

Comment: Then you should ask a question that describes how you update your UI. You still haven't described that even a little, nor included any sample code that explains it, even though it's the core of the problem you're having. Your code in this question, for example, loads an array but doesn't touch your UI at all.

Comment: I found the reason the error is occurring. So basically my core data becomes “data: <fault>” unless I change the screens.

Comment: Core Data faults are not an error condition. I already suggested reading Apple's docs on how Core Data works. Please, do yourself a favor and take a look. You're making things hard on yourself here.